# Call function on directive parent scope with directive scope argument

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I am developing a directive which shows and hides it's contents based on a click event (ng-click) defined in it's template. On some views where the directive is used I'd like to be able to know if the directive is currently showing or hiding it's contents so I can respond to the DOM changes. The directive has isolated scope and I am trying to notify the parent scope when the directive has been "toggled". I'm attempting to accomplish this by passing a callback function to the directive where it is used that can be called when the directive's state changes i.e hides or shows

I'm not sure how to correctly implement this being that the state of the directive (hidden or shown) is stored in the directive's isolated scope and is determined after the ng-click. Therefore I need to call the parent scope's function from within the directive and not from withing the view.

This will make WAAY more sense with an example. Here is a plunked demonstrating what I'd like to do:

http://plnkr.co/edit/hHwwxjssOKiphTSO1VIS?p=info

```
var app = angular.module('main-module',[])

app.controller('MainController', function($scope){
  $scope.myValue = 'test value';
  $scope.parentToggle = function(value){
    $scope.myValue = value;
  };
});

app.directive('toggle', function(){
    return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<a ng-click="toggle();">Click Me</a>',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                OnToggle: '&'
            },
            link: function($scope, elem, attrs, controller) {
                $scope.toggleValue = false;
                $scope.toggle = function () {
                    $scope.toggleValue = !$scope.toggleValue;
                    $scope.OnToggle($scope.toggleValue)
                };
            }
        };
});
```

I'm relatively new to Angular. Is this a bad idea to begin with? Should I be using a service or something rather than passing around function refs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**Update**

You can also use `&` to bind the function of the root scope (that is actually the purpose of `&`).

To do so the directive needs to be slightly changed:

```
app.directive('toggle', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<a ng-click="f()">Click Me</a>',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      toggle: '&'
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.toggleValue = false;
      $scope.f = function() {
        $scope.toggleValue = !$scope.toggleValue;
        $scope.toggle({message: $scope.toggleValue});
      };
    }
  };
});
```

You can use like this:

```
<div toggle="parentToggle(message)"></div>
```

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/kzPRxAdG24Y7k0xFanZP?p=preview)

---

You could bind the function using `=`. In addition ensure the property name in your scope and tag are matching (AngularJS translates CamelCase to *dash notation*).

Before:

```
scope: {
  OnToggle: '&'
}
```

After:

```
scope: {
  onToggle: '='
}
```

Furthermore don't use `on-toggle="parentToggle({value: toggleValue})"` in your main template. You do not want to call the function but just passing a *pointer* of the function to the directive.

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/9fusO7XsunFkpXxXkgIJ?p=preview)

Comment: @Nick I digged a bit deeper and added an alternative using `&` to bind the function of the root scope. Maybe this is more *Angularish*.

Comment: Your plunker does exactly what I'm trying to do, but I'm having trouble porting it in to my code.  Is there a reason it wouldn't work for an Element-type directive?  Or is there anything I would need to do differently?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by element-type directive. In case want to use an element (`restrict: 'E'`) instead of an attribute (`restrict: 'A'`) in your HTML this would work in the same way (e.g. `<toggle on-toggle="parentToggle"></toggle>`).

Comment: I'm having the same issue but trying to use a method in the grand-parent scope. It works fine when I'm accessing the method from the child directive, but doesn't "bubble up" from the grand-child directive...

Comment: oh, man - I've spent 4 hours on this until I found this answer! Works well!

Comment: These two line $scope.toggle({message: $scope.toggleValue}); and <div toggle="parentToggle(message)"></div> gave me solution for my problem. Thanks.

Comment: This is definitely one of the best, most straight-forward examples I've seen of this. Thanks!