# angularjs directive controller function executes many time

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In angularjs , I am making a treeview using directive.

```
return {
        restrict: "E",
        //replace: true,
        scope: {member: '=', ShowDetailsCtrlFunc : '&'},
        template: "<li><span ng-click=ShowDetailsCtrlFunc()>{{member.NodeName}}</span></li>",       
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        link: linkerfunc        
    }
```

Things are fine, but i observed that controller function calls multiple times while loading.  Would be a great learning if explain me the concept behind this.  Or is it possible to handle this and let the function execute only once ? I have created below plunker for same.

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EQy9F0C9Uu37JFKVTAn3?p=preview)

Thanks

Comment: you have added controller: 'MainCtrl', which triggers the controller, since you need to use $scope.ShowDetailsCtrlFunc function on controller you need to use controller: 'MainCtrl'. Maybe you can use a rootScope check for the $timeout(function(){ $scope.Intialfunc(); }, 1000); not execute only once

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15681173/4222181

Comment: @twitch, the rootScope seems an option. I tried to implement but not now that click function ShowDetailsCtrlFunc  stopped working and shows undefined. the updated plunkr is , http://plnkr.co/edit/EQy9F0C9Uu37JFKVTAn3?p=preview

Comment: I am not if this will be of any help https://plnkr.co/edit/PMYsVZfaujHVK1MoVL6N?p=preview